# Point inside or in boundary of polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, boundary, point-in-polygon

I'm using the algorithm in http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html,
but when the input point is in boundary, that algorithm gives wrong for me. Can anyone help me with point in boundary case?
Any help is appreciated.

This is the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Polygon.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Point> v;
    //v.push_back(make_pair(3.0,3.0));
    v.push_back(make_pair(1.0,1.0));
    v.push_back(make_pair(1.0,5.0));
    v.push_back(make_pair(5.0,5.0));
    v.push_back(make_pair(5.0,1.0));
    Polygon *p = new Polygon(v);
    cout << "A: " << p->IsInside(make_pair(1.0,3.0)) << endl;
    cout << "B: " << p->IsInside(make_pair(3.0,1.0)) << endl;
    cout << "C: " << p->IsInside(make_pair(5.0,3.0)) << endl;
    cout << "D: " << p->IsInside(make_pair(3.0,5.0)) << endl;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the checking function

```
bool Polygon::IsInside(Point p)
{
    /*determine whether a point is inside a polygon or not
     *  polygon's vertices need to be sorted counterclockwise
     *  source :
     *      http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
    */
    bool ans = false;
    for(size_t c=0,d=this->vertices.size()-1; c<this->vertices.size(); d=c++)
    {
        if( ((this->vertices[c].y > p.y) != (this->vertices[d].y > p.y)) &&
            (p.x < (this->vertices[d].x - this->vertices[c].x) * (p.y - this->vertices[c].y) /
                (this->vertices[d].y - this->vertices[c].y) + this->vertices[c].x) )
           ans = !ans;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: You can precheck whether the point is on the boundary before running the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the website documentation:
"PNPOLY partitions the plane into points inside the polygon and points outside the polygon. Points that are on the boundary are classified as either inside or outside. ..."
Please read the documentation available on the site again.It answers your question.
In the end, you will probably have to to live with the ambiguity of floating point calculations.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question how to make the algorithm work with boundary points (neither does its documentation). Also, the reason the algorithm does not work on the boundary is not because of floating point inaccuracies but because it hasn't been designed to handle that case.